# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button click event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

In my C# code I have function to dynamically create buttons

```
private Button createPageButton(string id, string text, int navTo = 0)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = id;
    btn.Text = text;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnNavigate_To_Page);
    return btn;
}
```

Which gets setup like this:

**C#:**

```
public void someMethod()
{
    Button btnPage_First = createPageButton("btnFirst_Page", "First", 1);
    panelNavPageButtons.Controls.Add(btnPage_First);
}
```

**aspx:**

```
 <asp:Panel ID="panelPageNavButtons" CssClass="pageNavBtns" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

**Problem:** The btnNavigate_To_Page event does not fire. The createPageButton method is *not called within Page_Load* but if I include an asp button in the panel (see below) then any additional button I add on the server side works properly

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelPageNavButtons" CssClass="pageNavBtns" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPage_Prev" runat="server" OnClick="btnNavigate_To_Page" />
 </asp:Panel>
```

I would like to set up all the buttons dynamically without including any reference to **btnNavigate_To_Page** in the .aspx file

Comment: If you create dynamic buttons, you have to recreate them every time there is a PostBack. So you have to keep track of all the buttons you create with `createPageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `someMethod` method inside either `Init` or `Load` event.

The reason is dynamically created controls are not in the control tree, so you have to reload them on every post back with ***same id***.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someMethod();
}
```

Comment: I just realized I'm already doing this, the buttons show up and stay there...someMethod just happens to be called within the context of anotherMethod which gets called in PageInit on every post back...The trouble is I still can't get that event to fire